# Capture and compile a list of names from a log file

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I need a one-line command to compile and print all of the Expendable Launch Vehicle names listed in a log file.

The ELV names are all listed in capital letters under the `/elv` directory.

The output should appear in the format of one name per line, with no duplicates:

```
ALICE
BOB
CHARLIE
```

I tried

```
grep "GET" NASA_access_log_Aug95.txt | grep "ELV" | wc -l
```

but it only showed me the number of ELV not printed ELV names

Below is a sample of my log file `NASA_access_log_Aug95.txt`:

```
cc-rd6-mg1-dip4-9.massey.ac.nz - - [03/Aug/1995:20:43:31 -0400] "GET /elv/TITAN/mars1s.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 1156
www-a2.proxy.aol.com - - [03/Aug/1995:20:43:31 -0400] "GET /elv/DELTA/dsolids.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 24558
cc-rd6-mg1-dip4-9.massey.ac.nz - - [03/Aug/1995:20:43:32 -0400] "GET /elv/TITAN/mars3s.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 1744
castor.gel.usherb.ca - - [03/Aug/1995:20:43:33 -0400] "GET /shuttle/missions/51-l/movies/ HTTP/1.0" 200 372
cc-rd6-mg1-dip4-9.massey.ac.nz - - [03/Aug/1995:20:43:33 -0400] "GET /elv/ATLAS_CENTAUR/atc69s.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 1659
cc-rd6-mg1-dip4-9.massey.ac.nz - - [03/Aug/1995:20:43:35 -0400] "GET /elv/TITAN/mars2s.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 1549
palona1.cns.hp.com - - [03/Aug/1995:20:43:36 -0400] "GET /shuttle/missions/sts-69/count69.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 46053
www-c1.proxy.aol.com - - [03/Aug/1995:20:43:38 -0400] "GET /shuttle/missions/sts-71/images/KSC-95EC-0882.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 51289
cc-rd6-mg1-dip4-9.massey.ac.nz - - [03/Aug/1995:20:43:40 -0400] "GET /elv/ATLAS_CENTAUR/acsuns.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 2263
cc-rd6-mg1-dip4-9.massey.ac.nz - - [03/Aug/1995:20:43:41 -0400] "GET /elv/ATLAS_CENTAUR/goess.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 1306
cc-rd6-mg1-dip4-9.massey.ac.nz - - [03/Aug/1995:20:43:45 -0400] "GET /elv/DELTA/dsolidss.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 1629
```

Answer (score 6):

You need just:

```
awk -F'/' '/elv/ && !seen[$5]++ {print $5}' infile
```

This prints the fifth field per slash `/` as the field separator, if it's not previously set in the array named `seen` as well as the line should contain `elv`. See also *[How does awk '!a[$0]++' work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159695/how-does-awk-a0-work)* and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10842118/explain-this-duplicate-line-removing-order-retaining-one-line-awk-command/10842212#10842212) on Stack Overflow.

For the given sample, the output would be:

```
TITAN
DELTA
ATLAS_CENTAUR
```

Comment: `/GET \/elv\//` or `$4 == "elv"` might be better search commands in case `elv` also appears in the host name or other path parts.

Answer (score 6):

I would just use `grep` and `sort -u`:

```
$ grep -Po '/elv/\K[^/]+' NASA_access_log_Aug95.txt | sort -u
ATLAS_CENTAUR
DELTA
TITAN
```

The `-P` enables Perl Compatible Regular Expressions which let us use `\K` which means "ignore anything matched up to this point". The `-o` means "only show the matching portion of the line". Then, the regular expression means "look for `/elv/`, ignore everything matched until the `/elv/`, and then look for one or more non-`/` characters (`[^/]+`).

Answer (score 5):

You can do it like this:

```bsh
grep 'elv' NASA_access_log_Aug95.txt | awk '{print $7}' | sed 's/[a-z0-9./]//g' | sort -u
```

Given your example snippet from the log file this will output:

```bsh
ATLAS_CENTAUR
DELTA
TITAN
```

Explanation of the piped commands in order they occur:

- `grep 'elv' NASA_access_log_Aug95.txt`

  Will output you all lines containing `elv`

  ```
  cc-rd6-mg1-dip4-9.massey.ac.nz - - [03/Aug/1995:20:43:31 -0400] "GET /elv/TITAN/mars1s.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 1156
  www-a2.proxy.aol.com - - [03/Aug/1995:20:43:31 -0400] "GET /elv/DELTA/dsolids.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 24558
  cc-rd6-mg1-dip4-9.massey.ac.nz - - [03/Aug/1995:20:43:32 -0400] "GET /elv/TITAN/mars3s.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 1744
  cc-rd6-mg1-dip4-9.massey.ac.nz - - [03/Aug/1995:20:43:33 -0400] "GET /elv/ATLAS_CENTAUR/atc69s.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 1659
  cc-rd6-mg1-dip4-9.massey.ac.nz - - [03/Aug/1995:20:43:35 -0400] "GET /elv/TITAN/mars2s.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 1549
  cc-rd6-mg1-dip4-9.massey.ac.nz - - [03/Aug/1995:20:43:40 -0400] "GET /elv/ATLAS_CENTAUR/acsuns.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 2263
  cc-rd6-mg1-dip4-9.massey.ac.nz - - [03/Aug/1995:20:43:41 -0400] "GET /elv/ATLAS_CENTAUR/goess.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 1306
  cc-rd6-mg1-dip4-9.massey.ac.nz - - [03/Aug/1995:20:43:45 -0400] "GET /elv/DELTA/dsolidss.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 1629
  ```
- `awk '{print $7}'`

  Will give you the 7th column information (the one you want). Remember That this counts colums divided by spaces.

  ```
  /elv/TITAN/mars1s.jpg
  /elv/DELTA/dsolids.jpg
  /elv/TITAN/mars3s.jpg
  /elv/ATLAS_CENTAUR/atc69s.jpg
  /elv/TITAN/mars2s.jpg
  /elv/ATLAS_CENTAUR/acsuns.jpg
  /elv/ATLAS_CENTAUR/goess.jpg
  /elv/DELTA/dsolidss.jpg
  ```
- `sed 's/[a-z0-9./]//g'`

  Will filter out all unwanted characters (i.e. lower case `a-z`, numbers `0-9`, `.` and `/`)

  ```
  TITAN
  DELTA
  TITAN
  ATLAS_CENTAUR
  TITAN
  ATLAS_CENTAUR
  ATLAS_CENTAUR
  DELTA
  ```
- `sort -u`

  Will prevent duplicates from appearing and sorts them alphabetically.

  ```
  ATLAS_CENTAUR
  DELTA
  TITAN
  ```

Comment: `tr -d a-z0-9./` would suffice in place of `sed`.

Answer (score 5):

With Perl, regex matching the `/`-delimited elements after `elv` and pushing them into a hash:

```
$ perl -lne '$h{$1}++ if m:/elv/(.*?)/: }{ for $k (sort keys %h) {print $k}' NASA_access_log_Aug95.txt 
ATLAS_CENTAUR
DELTA
TITAN
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also use `sed` with just a little help from `sort`

```
$ sed -rn '\|/elv/| s|.*/elv/([^/]+).*|\1|p' NASA_access_log_Aug95.txt | sort -u
ATLAS_CENTAUR
DELTA
TITAN
```

#### Explanation

- `-r` Use extended regex (saves a couple of backslashes)
- `-n` Don't print the lines we don't ask for
- `\|/elv/|` find lines with `/elv/` (the `\|` at the start means use `|` not `/` to delimit the address)
- `s|old|new|` replace `old` with `new`
- `.*/elv/` any characters before and including `/elv/`
- `([^/]+)` save all the characters until the next `/`
- `.*` any number of any characters
- `\1` reference to the characters we saved
- `p` print the lines we worked on
- `sort -u` sort the input and remove duplicates